# Cassandra: export from one keyspace to another

Tags: cassandra, cql

I'm still trying to figure my way in Cassandra world and I managed to successfully import some legacy stuff from a MySQL to Cassandra in a 'legacy_imports' keyspace.

The problem is, my working version is in an other keyspace 'stats' and I'd like to keep 'legacy_imports' with me somewhere and merge it on 'stats' as well.
So the wanted operation here is just to **copy some tables** (including COUNTER tables) **from a keyspace to another** on the same node.

I tried to `COPY ... TO` but I had an error :
`<ErrorMessage code=0000 [Server error] message="com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Operation timed out - received only 1 responses.">`

I also tried sstableloader but I had a hard time working with it. My data is split on 2 disks and paths looks like this :

`/media/disk2/cassandra/data/legacy_imports/log_by_day-1e6b7de0a90111e49471715135b1c904/snapshots/1422680322490-log_by_day/legacy_imports-log_by_day-ka-1-Data.db`

When I try sstableloader, in legacy_imports directory, I get :

`Could not retrieve endpoint ranges: 
InvalidRequestException(why:No such keyspace: snapshots)`

And finally if I do it only on legacy_imports, I get :

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableLoader.<init>(SSTableLoader.java:71)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader.main(BulkLoader.java:79)`

Answer (score 1):

The COPY command is unfortunately not very performant prior to C* 2.1 so it does run into issues occasionally. The particular error you are receiving is because one of the reads was being preformed but the result was not obtained within your timeout parameter. Note that it did say it received one response which means at least one node was able to respond in time. This means you may be ok with a lower consistency level.

I think the best (and scalable solution) is to use something like spark to do the transfer. Something like

```
sc.cassandraTable("firstKeyspace","legacy_table").saveToCassandra("secondKeyspace","otherTable")
```

Another solution is to write a short driver program to do this for you where your data is read from one table and written to the other. Here you can have a more finely adjusted write control so you can handle ReadTimeouts/WriteTimeouts or even transform data before re-writing it.

Comment: Hi @RussS, thanks for your help. I was afraid of such an answer as I was pushing back the moment I would integrate Spark but I think I can't push anymore. I thought I might use [Pachyderm.io](http://www.pachyderm.io/) to help me with this import so I can do it in Go. (I'm not so much of a Java devloper...). Do you have any advice on the choice between both ? Thanks again.

Comment: I really enjoy the spark platform and It looks like it will be a valuable platform to know in the future. Pretty much all of the big data world is humming with hype about spark right now. It's useful with C* because you can do a lot of complicated transformations in a pretty simple way. There is also a Python connector but it's only available with DSE atm.

Comment: Alright, so I did try this morning to install Spark and regrettably failed ... I'm going to import it by hand as it's a solution I'm sure of. Thanks anyway for your help !!

Answer (score 1):

Simply moving the SSTables into place should work. The procedure is basically:

1. Create the tables in the `stats` keyspace
2. Copy the SSTables to the appropriate data directory under `stats`
3. `nodetool refresh -- stats legacy_table`

Comment: Hi Gordon,
I tried this but it didn't work. `Nodetool refresh` didn't output any error but I still don't have my data in the `stats` keyspace. As said to @RussS, I'm going to do this by hand, with CQL Batch so I'm sure I can't fail.